# How to create own Maven Repository?

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository

I want to know, how to create my own dependency to use my code in other projects.

I were following tutorial.
I`ve tried to create project with simple class as Maven Project.
I did clean-package. Created github repository. Added my project there with "target" package.
in pom.xml i added

```xml
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
        <github.maven-plugin>0.12</github.maven-plugin>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal.repo</id>
            <name>Temporary Staging Repository</name>
            <url>file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <altDeploymentRepository>internal.repo::default::file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</altDeploymentRepository>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${github.maven-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <message>Maven artifacts for ${project.version}</message>
                    <noJekyll>true</noJekyll>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</outputDirectory>
                    <branch>refs/heads/mvn-repo</branch>
                    <includes><include>**/*</include></includes>
                    <repositoryName>GITHUB_NAME_REPOSITORY</repositoryName>
                    <repositoryOwner>MY_GITHUB_NICKNAME</repositoryOwner>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>site</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

after in root of .m2 directory i created settings.xml with:

```xml
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>[username]</username>
      <password>[password]</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

did again clean+package and pushed to github.

after trying to use dependency - not found.
in github repo no mvn-repo branch

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used the new GitHub repositories yet, but what work quite well so far:

- private, single machine usage: `mvn install` -> the artifact will be installed in your local Maven repository and can be referenced by any other project on the same machine
- Open Source, multiple machines/ developers: `mvn deploy` to [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/). See the [documentation](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html) for more information about configuration and involved steps.
- Closed Source, multiple machines/ developers: `mvn deploy` to your own Maven Repository manager such as [Nexus](https://de.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) (configure the distributionManagement accordingly)

That said, it's a [best practice](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) to use your own Maven Repository Manager in all 3 cases and define a [single group](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/maven-repositories#MavenRepositories-ConfiguringApacheMaven).

From the [Maven default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) documentation:

> **package**:  take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
>
> **install**:  install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally.
>
> **deploy**:     done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

Comment: thanks, i did deploy instead of package and it works. I thought that in pom.xml plugins it will prepare for deploy by "packaging" and after i`ll push it by myself

Comment: @ekstra777 see the default Maven lifecycle documentation for more information about the phases: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference